# Spring Data JPA и магические слова

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Есть нативный запрос, который при тесте не работает, не могу найти ошибку.

Базовая Entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class BaseModel {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@Getter
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

protected BaseModel() {
  }
}
```

Entity Teacher:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public final class Teacher extends BaseModel {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
private PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String surname;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String discipline;

public Teacher() {
  }
}
```

Entity Pupil:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pupil")
public final class Pupil extends BaseModel {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pupil_iD")
private PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Getter
@Setter
@Column(nullable = false)
private String surname;

public Pupil() {

  }
}
```

Entity ClassRoom:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_room")
public final class ClassRoom extends BaseModel {

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "class_Room_id")
private PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

public ClassRoom() {
   }
}
```

Entity PupilInClassRoom:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pupil_in_class_room")
public final class PupilInClassRoom  extends BaseModel {

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pupilInClassRoom")
@Getter
@Setter
private Pupil pupil;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pupilInClassRoom")
@Getter
@Setter
private ClassRoom classRoom;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "pupilInClassRoom")
@Getter
@Setter
private Teacher teacher;

public PupilInClassRoom() {

}
```

Запрос:

```
public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil,Long> {
List<Pupil> findByName(String name);

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.surname " +
        "FROM pupil p " +
        "INNER JOIN pupil_in_class_room in ON p.pupil_id = in.id " +
        "INNER JOIN teacher t ON t.teacher_id = in.id " +
        "WHERE t.name = :name ")
List<Pupil> findPupilByTeacher(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Cуть запроса, вывести учеников по имени учителя

Тест:

```
@Test
@Rollback(value = false)
public void createEntity() {
    Pupil pupil = new Pupil();
    pupil.setName("Hello");
    pupil.setSurname("hello");

    Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
    teacher.setName("Alla");
    teacher.setSurname("Aronova");
    teacher.setDiscipline("Mat");

    ClassRoom classRoom = new ClassRoom();
    classRoom.setName("1A");

    PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom = new PupilInClassRoom();
    teacher.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);
    pupil.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);
    classRoom.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);


    pupilInClassRoomRepository.save(pupilInClassRoom);
    teacherRepository.save(teacher);
    pupilRepository.save(pupil);
    classRoomRepository.save(classRoom);


    Iterable<Pupil> allPupil = pupilRepository.findAll();
    for (Pupil pupil1 : allPupil) {
        System.out.println("Ученики");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(pupil1.getId() + " " +
                pupil1.getName() + " " +
                pupil1.getSurname());
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }

    Iterable<Teacher> allTeacher = teacherRepository.findAll();
    for (Teacher teacher1 : allTeacher) {
        System.out.println("Учителя");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(teacher1.getId() + " " +
                teacher1.getName() + " " +
                teacher1.getSurname() + " " +
                teacher1.getDiscipline());
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }
    Iterable<ClassRoom> allClassRoom = classRoomRepository.findAll();
    for (ClassRoom classRoom1 : allClassRoom) {
        System.out.println("Класс");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(classRoom1.getId() + " "
                +classRoom1.getName());
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
    }

    Iterable<PupilInClassRoom> allPupilInClassRoom = pupilInClassRoomRepository.findAll();
    for (PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom1 : allPupilInClassRoom) {
        System.out.println("Ученики в классе");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(pupilInClassRoom1.getPupil().getId() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getPupil().getName() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getPupil().getSurname());

        System.out.println(pupilInClassRoom1.getTeacher().getId() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getTeacher().getName() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getTeacher().getSurname() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getTeacher().getDiscipline());

        System.out.println(pupilInClassRoom1.getClassRoom().getId() + " " +
                pupilInClassRoom1.getClassRoom().getName());
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println("Поиск ученика по учителю");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println(pupilRepository.findPupilByTeacher(pupilInClassRoom.getTeacher().getName()));
}
```

Результат работы теста:

```
Ученики
----------------------------
3 Hello hello
----------------------------
Учителя
----------------------------
2 Alla Aronova Mat
----------------------------
Класс
----------------------------
4 1A
----------------------------
Ученики в классе
----------------------------
3 Hello hello
2 Alla Aronova Mat
4 1A
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.Teacher.getName()" because the return value of "com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.PupilInClassRoom.getTeacher()" is null
```

Новый Exception если заинъектить "name":

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.PupilInClassRoom] for value '{3, 1, Hello, hello}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.math.BigInteger] to type [com.SchoolJournal.SpringHibernate.model.PupilInClassRoom]
```

Возможно ли в данном случае отказаться от нативного @Query и использовать магические слова Spring Data?

Comment: Приложите ошибку, чтоб понять где бросается исключение или пометьте в коде. Вы используете nativeQuery, при этом есть алиас `pupil_in_class_room in`, так вот, `in` это зарезервированное слово в sql. Запрос переписать можно на jpql или названием метода.

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил. я пробовал и не через in, это не меняет сути.

Comment: Обратил внимание, что все связи сделаны через OneToOne и соответственно все поля могут находится не на той стороне как ожидаете. В таблице `pupil_in_class_room `  отсутствует поле `teacher_id ` . Эта связь находится в классе `Teacher.pupilInClassRoom`, а поле в БД `teacher_id` . И условие в sql вместо `ON 
t.id = in.teacher_id` должно быть `ON t.teacher_id = in.id` . Лучше все правильно именовать, тогда такие ошибки будут быстро находиться.

Comment: @MrFylypenko я исправил запрос, верно?

Comment: @MrFylypenko только запрос пустой возвращается, хотя должен вывести одного человека

Comment: @RomanKonoval Подправил, возможно ли такой запрос свернуть до типа findPupilByTeacher, как это реализовано к примеру findByName?

Comment: Как я и писал, при OneToOne поля содержащие ид хранятся не на той стороне как ожидаете, и сохранение сущностей должно происходить в другом порядке. Сначала должен сохранятся PupilInClassRoom (в бд нет ссылки на teacher и pupil), а потом сохранить teacher, псевдокод: `save(<PupilInClassRoom>); Teacher teacher = new Teacher(); teacher.setPupilInClassRoom(<PupilInClassRoom>) ; save(teacher)`.

Comment: @MrFylypenko добавил тест в топик, это нормально что id такие присвоились? Твое сообщение помогло, только запрос не работает еще)

Comment: ИД присвоились нормальные.  Почему не работает запрос не знаю. В добавленном тесте не вижу строки в конце `System.out.println((pupilRepository.findPupilByTeacher(pupilInClassRoom.getTeacher().getName())));`, есть какой-нибудь результат ? в sql запросе выбираются не все значения, отсутствует pupil_iD после id в select, может и в этом проблема

Comment: @MrFylypenko обновил тест, поймал нулпоинтер.

Comment: в тесте не было выполнено `pupilInClassRoom.setTeacher(teacher);` вот и NPE, но это другой вопрос. А если выполнить `System.out.println((pupilRepository.findPupilByTeacher("Alla")));` ?

Comment: @MrFylypenko вылетает ошибка, зачем выполнять `pupilInClassRoom.setTeacher(teacher);`? я добавил ради интереса эту строчку ничего не изменилось, тоже ошибка, по поводу `System.out.println((pupilRepository.findPupilByTeacher("Alla")));` Выходит ошибка, обновил топик

Comment: @MrFylypenko дал ответ на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение первого вопроса это правильные сеттеры и правильная последовательность сохранения в репозиторий при `@OneToOne`, как подсказал [MrFylypenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218319/mrfylypenko)

```
PupilInClassRoom pupilInClassRoom = new PupilInClassRoom();
teacher.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);
pupil.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);
classRoom.setPupilInClassRoom(pupilInClassRoom);

pupilInClassRoomRepository.save(pupilInClassRoom);
teacherRepository.save(teacher);
pupilRepository.save(pupil);
classRoomRepository.save(classRoom);
```

Решение второго вопроса отказаться от нативного Query используя магически слова

```
public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil,Long> {
    List<Pupil> findByName(String name);

    List<Pupil> findByPupilInClassRoomTeacherName(String name);
}
```